# Embedding metadata in ConversationalRetrievalChain answer

Tags: metadata, langchain, conversational-ai

I am relatively new to Langchain.

I am using **ConversationalRetrievalChain** to 'chat' with data in PDFs.
I got to a point where I ask a question and get a good answer. However, this is not enough in my case. **I would like the answer to embed pdfs identifier/name (which is stored in the metadata of the docs) in the answer itself.**

For example:
question: what are the top 3 trending aluminum profiles?
answer: the top 3 aluminum trending aluminum profiles are Brook with thickness of 3 milimiters and green-metal color (metadata: doc01), Ispahan with thickness of 2 milimiter and dark blue color (metadata: doc02) and Jordalish with 1 milimiter thickness and black color (metadata: doc03).

I can loop through the retrieved docs and create a list, however, this will not allow me to point the correct doc to its part in the returned answer.

Would highly appreciate any help. Thanks!

The closest I got is looping through the metadata of the retrieved docs, however this does not solve my problem.

Comment: Hi, @user2295798! I can help you out since I solved a similar problem. But to do so, first, you'll need to provide some additional details: 1) Are you using Python or JS LangChani? 2) What vector store are you using?

Comment: Hello @RodrigoVegaMoreno,
Thank you for your response. To answer your questions:
1. Python
2. vectorstore: Chroma: self.__vectorstore = Chroma(persist_directory=dir, embedding_function=embedding)

Comment: did you find an answer? @user2295798

Comment: Nope. Not really. @Asim